# Turning Webcam and Light off with GWT Elemental

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I found this great piece of code to turn web camera on and take pictures, but sadly, I can't figure out a way to turn the webcam off. There are no methods to call for that to happen, and even the call to turn the camera on from GWT is with the use of native JavaScript, which I am not very familiar with at the moment.. Any thoughts? Here is the code:

```
public native static boolean getUserVideo(UserWebcamCallback callback)/*-{
        if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) {
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(
                {video: true, toString: function() {return "video";}},
                function(stream) {
                    var s = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    $entry(callback.@com.test.ElementalUtils.UserWebcamCallback::onSuccess(Ljava/lang/String;)(s));
                    },
                function() {
                    $entry(callback.@com.test.ElementalUtils.UserWebcamCallback::onFail()());
                });
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }-*/;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew! Thought I was going to have sleepless nights on this one. 
The trick was to add a "localStream" global variable to the code, and close the stream in another method. Like this:

```
    public native static boolean getUserVideo(UserWebcamCallback callback)/*-{
            localStream;
            if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) {
                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(
                    {video: true, toString: function() {return "video";}},
                    function(stream) {
                        var s = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

            localStream = stream;
                        $entry(callback.@com.test.ElementalUtils.UserWebcamCallback::onSuccess(Ljava/lang/String;)(s));
                        },
                    function() {
                        $entry(callback.@com.test.ElementalUtils.UserWebcamCallback::onFail()());
                    });
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }-*/;

public native static void stopVideo()/*-{
localStream.getTracks()[0].stop();
}-*/
```

Comment: As a thought, instead of leaving it as a global variable, make it a static field in the Java class, so that some future compiler optimization doesn't get confused and give each JSNI method a differently named `localStream` - this can happen if you use the Closure Compiler, and is annoying to have to debug.

Comment: OK. Noted. But do you mean a static field as a java variable or still in JavaScript? I wouldn't even begin to know what data type a JavaScript stream is in Java

Comment: It can simply be a `JavaScriptObject` or `Object` - JS won't care what type it is, and without actually doing this work in Java (consider that, by the way, either with a JSO subtype or JsInterop), you won't need a specific type in Java for it, just a field so the compiler handles it correctly. More details on JSNI/JSOs http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html

Comment: BTW bonus points for you on the _almost_ correct use of `$entry()`, most people don't get even that far. Instead, pass the `function() {...}` into it. You won't notice problems with doing it your way, but that's the issue if you'll pardon the double meaning: your UncaughtExceptionHandler won't notice exceptions from the callback, and any Scheduler usage will misbehave (but only slightly).